# Too much white space around jasper subreport

Tags: jasperserver

There is too much white space produced before and after a subreport in a pdf file generated using jasper.
Any help to eliminate the space around subreport component will help a lot.

Here is the main report template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.12.2.final using JasperReports Library version 6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="with_sub_report" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="256c6d62-ba9b-404c-8e1c-eaeeca988125">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="JOURNAL_WITH_PAYMENT"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="JOURNAL_WITH_PAYMENT.xml"/>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[entries]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="jouranl_date" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="jouranl_date"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[jouranl_date]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="journal_ref" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="journal_ref"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[journal_ref]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="journal_line" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="journal_line"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[journal_line]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="amount" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="amount"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[amount]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="crncy" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="crncy"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[crncy]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="dr_or_cr" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="dr_or_cr"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[dr_or_cr]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="34" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="5" width="100" height="25" uuid="0d465cec-66da-4e16-829e-c8728f0b770e"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Journal Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="150" y="5" width="100" height="25" uuid="c4dac4a0-f457-4700-b7ac-1d3b31604f62"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Journal Ref Num]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="290" y="5" width="100" height="25" uuid="81c750c7-2df3-4200-89e7-b8535b3193a5"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Journal line]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="-10" y="4" width="120" height="16" uuid="f5f87f9d-fc7d-44ae-8c13-63b49db240ec">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="2e697f8a-57a8-4d0e-8faa-47180c6b44ae"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{jouranl_date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="150" y="4" width="100" height="16" uuid="cf85e544-bef5-4e5b-9e73-7704a2bd4c5a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="6c255841-3412-410f-a976-b3ec67868bc3"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{journal_ref}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="290" y="4" width="100" height="16" uuid="2b8664a2-652e-4426-9f8d-746286f7a12e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="1f3fb198-93d5-4592-b33e-4a61a1a9513b"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{journal_line}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport overflowType="Stretch">
                <reportElement x="-18" y="13" width="30" height="7" uuid="64cc178b-58b5-4273-ad0d-ea75d2c2524e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new String("C").equals(($F{dr_or_cr}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="dr_or_cr">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{dr_or_cr}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="crncy">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{crncy}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="amount">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{amount}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["payment_sub_report.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="52" splitType="Prevent">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="232" y="22" width="100" height="30" uuid="3fcd32ad-45a6-4153-9d0e-2a7c9f9f44d8"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Static Text]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

And here is the subreport

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.12.2.final using JasperReports Library version 6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="payment_sub_report" pageWidth="549" pageHeight="30" columnWidth="549" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="aa23536f-b74a-40f9-911a-b1cbfad0a6a3">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="dr_or_cr" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="crncy" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="amount" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="29" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="-12" y="4" width="100" height="16" uuid="ca02c58c-8c11-4354-9ebb-76a807062e46"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{dr_or_cr}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="183" y="4" width="100" height="16" uuid="763524dc-97d5-4e40-9dee-ad53d2d11be2"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{crncy}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="385" y="4" width="100" height="16" uuid="06f2e836-3420-4dff-b512-4ba837b0d1c6"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Moreover the subreport comes too much to the right inspite of placing it to the exteme left in the main report

The output is uploaded here in this link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/117lFxIBE34gVdl7WkaG9Y_G_3f-Vx79l/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share the output?

Comment: I have uploaded the output in this location.    https://drive.google.com/file/d/117lFxIBE34gVdl7WkaG9Y_G_3f-Vx79l/view?usp=sharing